# Magento2 5 cent rounding

Tags: magento2, price, rounding

in magento 1.x for price roud i used extension https://github.com/openstream/Magento5CentRounding
Does have somebody any solution for magento 2, or which functions i need rewrite ?

Is https://marketplace.magento.com/pits-module-five-cent-rounding.html a good option?

Comment: Where you want to round the price ?

Comment: after looking this extension I think you want to round the price on checkout page.

Comment: @Ramkishan i want to round in catalog, cart, checkout, order, invoice, shipping, emails

Comment: if you round of price at checkout then round of price will save on db and you will see round price on order,invoice,shipping and emails

Comment: And for catalog and cart where is mean of round of price ?

Comment: @Ramkishan in category listing, product detail page, mini cart in header

Comment: so you want at product listing page(frontend) round of price should be there for that product. Is it so ?

Comment: @Ramkishan example:
I have product price 65.00, and apply catalog price rulles, after that price will be 55,23, i want to round price in frontend to 55,25

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For round the price on checkout page you need to extend

**magento2/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Grand.php** file.

for rounding grandtotal or base grandtotal in your grand.php (which you have extend) in collect method.

```
 $total->setGrandTotal(round($totals,0));
 $total->setBaseGrandTotal(round($baseTotals,0));
```

Using preference you can do this easily.
Let me know if you need further assistance. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

We looked into this quite a bit. The following options currently exist:

- [comsolit/rappenrunden](https://github.com/comsolit/mage2_rappenrunden): This repository is unmaintained and therefore e.g. not PHP 8 compatible. However, it still seems to work.
- [openstream/mage2_rappenrunden](https://github.com/openstream/mage2_rappenrunden/): This is a supported fork from `comsolit/rappenrunden`. It comes with PHP 8 support and some smaller fixes. It seems to work.
- [faonni/module-price](https://github.com/karliuka/m2.Price): This module actually provides some more price rounding algorithms. Only one of those is the Swiss 5 Rappen rounding. It seems to be maintained and also seems to work.
- [smiso/flexible-price-rounding](https://github.com/smiso/magento2.flexible-price-rounding): This is a fork from `faonni/module-price`, but honestly, I have no idea which advantage it provides compared to the original module.

All these modules have one flaw, though: If you use qty decimals and e.g. sell a quantity of 1.4 for a product with a unit price of 8.90, they fail. 1.4 * 8.90 makes a row total of 12.46, which would need to be rounded to 12.45. However, all these modules only round the unit price of 8.90, which does not work in this case. We wrote our own module to fix this, but we cannot publish it at the moment. It pretty much overrides `\Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation\AbstractAggregateCalculator::calculateWithTaxInPrice` and rounds the `$rowTotalInclTax` in this method.